# Validate NT User via SQL CLR

Tags: c#, .net, sql, clr, impersonation

I need to be able to validate a given username and password against Active Directory and return whether that user exists.

My setup is that I have two web servers in a DMZ, and then a SQL Server in the LAN.  The sales people have a admin panel that is on the web servers.  When they login to the admin panel, I want it to run a stored procedure that will validate the username and password against the Active Directory on the LAN side (since the web servers do not have access to Active Directory).  I tried making a SQL Stored Proc that does the following:

```
#region setup impersonation via interop
public const int LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE = 2;
public const int LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT = 0;

[DllImport("ADVAPI32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
public static extern bool LogonUser
    (
        string lpszUsername,
        string lpszDomain,
        string lpszPassword,
        int dwLogonType,
        int dwLogonProvider,
        ref IntPtr phToken
    );
#endregion

[Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.SqlFunction]
public static SqlBoolean NTAuthenticateUser(SqlString UserName, SqlString Password)
{
    IntPtr token = IntPtr.Zero;

    return LogonUser
        (
            UserName.Value,
            "MYDOMAIN",
            Password.Value,
            LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE,
            LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT,
            ref token
        );

    return true;
}
```

However when I go to put it on the SQL Server, I get the error

```
CREATE ASSEMBLY failed because type "UserDefinedFunctions" in external_access assembly "SQLCLR" has a pinvokeimpl method. P/Invoke is not allowed in external_access assemblies.
```

Which happens because the solution is set to EXTERNAL permission level and apparently calling ASVAPI32.DLL cannot occur unless the solution is set to UNSAFE permission level(?).

So (finally) my question - is there some way to do this while still running the CLR with EXTERNAL permissions?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest building a  secure webservice that encapsulates your code. Then call it from SQL CRL or your web app.

HTH